# Encog Analyst Wizard using time-series crashes. Bug found

Tags: time-series, encog

I'm trying to use the Encog Analyst Wizard 3.3.0 C# in code. Works ok when not using time-series but will set input count to 0 if LagWindowSize > 0.

```
        FileInfo rawFile = new FileInfo("data.csv");       // The one and only input
        FileInfo analystFile = new FileInfo("data.ega");   // Wizard output file

        EncogAnalyst encog = new EncogAnalyst();
        encog.AddAnalystListener(new ConsoleAnalystListener());
        AnalystWizard wiz = new AnalystWizard(encog);

        wiz.Goal = AnalystGoal.Regression;
        wiz.TargetFieldName = "Close";
        wiz.IncludeTargetField = true;
->>>>   wiz.LagWindowSize = 10;              // No inputCount if LagWindowSize > 0
        wiz.LeadWindowSize = 2; 

        wiz.TaskSegregate = true; 
        wiz.MaxError = 0.01;
        wiz.TaskNormalize = true;
        wiz.Range = NormalizeRange.Zero2One;    // Sigmoid

        wiz.TaskCluster = false;
        wiz.TaskRandomize = false;
        wiz.TaskBalance = false;

        wiz.Wizard(rawFile, true, AnalystFileFormat.DecpntComma);
//                              
// Crashes on task Create below because inputCount becomes 0 with.LagWindowSize > 0
// but works if wiz.LagWindowSize is set to 0 ... What am I missing here???
//
  ->>>>   encog.ExecuteTask("task-full");   // task-create fails !
```

Regards
Peter

Answer (score 1):

After some debugging I have found a bug in AnalystWizard.cs v3.3, private void ExpandTimeSlices() approx. line 700:

```
// swap back in
oldList.Clear(); // oldList is cleared and then used in a foreach …

// Original line:  foreach (AnalystField item in oldList)

// New line:
foreach (AnalystField item in newList)  // Correct list !!!
{
    oldList.Add(item);
}
```

These lines are only executed if  wiz.LagWindowSize > 0

Comment: Yes that is a bug.  I just checked in the suggested fix, it will be included in the next Encog version.  https://github.com/encog/encog-dotnet-core/commit/87b334dd0f45f4777aa9e02d7af5c5752ddaf3e6